# Laravel Vapor Response Streaming

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I currently have a docker image in a Lambda Function, using laravelphp/vapor:php82.  I am returning a streamed response from OpenAI's API, back to the browser.  On a normal server, this works fine.  But when I deploy into AWS using Laravel Vapor, the response is buffered, even when I configure output_buffering to off and implicit_flush to on.

What must I do to disable output buffering?

Comment: Experiencing this too, did you find a fix?

Comment: No I have not.  I have to assume others are going to have this issue too..